# Why can't I use my own ftp.exe?

Tags: windows-xp, ftp, emacs

I've been trying to configure FTP in Emacs22 on Windows XP, and I read [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AngeFtp) that the Windows ftp program wasn't up to scratch, and to replace it with [this GNU one](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/emacs/windows/contrib/ftp-for-win32.zip). That worked fine on my home computer, but on my work computer, if I put the new ftp.exe in System32, overwriting the old one, Windows instantly and silently replaces my version with its original version. Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is called [Windows File Protection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222193).

You have to replace the file in the directory `%systemroot%\system32\dllcache` also, as far as I remember, but try on your own risk.

Comment: Might be easier to just rename your `ftp.exe` to something else

Comment: Please, don't run around replacing random system files. You can put it elsewhere and name it differently.

Comment: Of cause: It is generally better to not modify the system files of your operating system, but I think there is no method how to do this without modifying any system files and he/she wanted to know a solution how to bypass this feature.

Comment: Manuel: One can always solve the problem by modifying the `PATH` environment variable for a single process.

Comment: A better solution would be to place the ftp client somewhere else then add it's location to the system path environment variable. If its entry is before the system32 Windows will find a run it first.

Comment: @Kenneth - this is actually the solution I came to in the end, but I didn't like the idea of having my own path before Windows' for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just change what program Emacs calls?

<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `ange-ftp-ftp-program-name` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Or add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(setq 'ange-ftp-ftp-program-name "my-ftp")
```